# how to use emoji picker lib in angularjs with directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I get this emoji lib :

https://github.com/one-signal/emoji-picker

I've thinking about make a directive, this is the function to use the emoji picker:

```
$(function() {
  // Initializes and creates emoji set from sprite sheet
  window.emojiPicker = new EmojiPicker({
    emojiable_selector: '[data-emojiable=true]',
    assetsPath: 'lib/img/',
    popupButtonClasses: 'fa fa-smile-o'
  });
  // Finds all elements with `emojiable_selector` and converts them to rich emoji input fields
  // You may want to delay this step if you have dynamically created input fields that appear later in the loading process
  // It can be called as many times as necessary; previously converted input fields will not be converted again
  window.emojiPicker.discover();
});
```

and this is the htlm use of the emoji:

```
  <p class="lead emoji-picker-container">
    <textarea class="form-control textarea-control" rows="3" placeholder="Textarea with emoji Unicode input" data-emojiable="true" data-emoji-input="unicode"></textarea>
  </p>
```

how could I do this for my angular project? thanks for helping me!

Comment: You probably want to take a look at previous work and start from there, typically SO is more for direct technical issues you encounter or specific questions https://github.com/one-signal/emoji-picker This Emoji picker is written without relying on jQuery so you can avoid having that extra dependency.  If you insist on using this library and wrapping it in a directive you'll need to load jQuery before angular but may find the other angular emoji library helpful for finding a starting point for organizing your directive code.

Answer (score 2):

[ng-emoji-picker](https://github.com/kimooz/ng-emoji-picker) is an angular directive for https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker

It removes the wysiwyg editor that [Original Emoji Picker](https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker) uses which converts your input/text area to a div and instead it just adds the emoji picker icon on the current textbox or input and uses unicode to add emojis

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for an emoji selector for Angular 2, I found this very useful jQuery plugin after two days of search:
[EmojiOne Area](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea)

If you want to call is to declare a global variable in your component (where you want to use it) like this `declare const jQuery: any` and then make sure to use it in `ngAfterViewInit()`. `ngAfterViewInit()` will make sure that your DOM is ready, otherwise you'll get an error saying that emojioneArea is not a function.

Use it like this by selecting your input element by its id or class: 
`jQuery(".your-input-selector").emojioneArea();`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this for EmojiOne Area with angular

```
// Document ready
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
}
```

The only issue I have is that when use it with a textarea within a `<md-input-container>`, it messes up the behaviour and the link with my model seams to be broken. Also the picker shows up under my other elements. I didnt try the ng-emoji-picker yet.

Answer (score -1):

Emoji-picker works fine with angular
easy to use as well.

with webpack import the lib

```
import 'angular-emoji-picker-extended/dist/js/emoji-picker';
```

in the view

```
<span container-id="txtPostMessage"  emoji-picker="post.message" output-format="unicode" placement="right-relative" title="Emoji"></span>
```

Make sure you initialise your model in the controller and voila !